# Refuse upload on routes in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, api, node.js, express

I have been working with ExpressJS to facilitate file uploads, but as far as I can see you could upload a file to any route regardless of it it handles it or not.

Say I have

`app.post('/photos/upload', photos.upload);`

I know I want a photo upload via that route so I can handle it, but what if someone uploads files to other routes? All those files are going to be written to the server, but not handled.

Is there a way to refuse uploads on all routes apart from ones I actually want files uploaded to?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing right now something like:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser())
```

which includes `express.multipart()` that handles file uploads. You'll just want to split this up:

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())

app.post('/photos/upload', express.multipart(), photos.upload)
```

Comment: Ah yes, that would seem to be the correct way of going about it. How would I specify the uploadDir using this method, like this `app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./somefolder'}));`

Edit: `app.post('/photos/upload', express.multipart({uploadDir:'./somefolder'}), photos.upload)`

Works just the same :)